# Optimize pairings of two types of points with respect to the maximum distance inside any pair

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, optimization

I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm for the following problem:
Given two different sets, both of size N. Each element in the two sets has coordinates (x,y).
The task is to optimize the pairings between these two sets such that the maximum distance between the paired elements given a pairing, is minimized.
I have only found algorithms that deal with the squared sum of all distances between paired elements or the smallest distance between any two points from the two different sets.
Any idea how can this be achieved in reasonable run time?  or name an algorithm that might help here.

For example:
Given a list of N pair of points that are associated with locations - (x0,y0), (x1,y1), (x2,y2)....( xn-1,yn-1), name them a0,a1,a2...aN-1 accordingly

And another list of N pairs of *different* points (locations)
(x0,y0), (x1,y1), (x2,y2)....( xn-1,yn-1), name them b0,b1,b2...bN-1 accordingly

How can I pair all elements (each element is  a pair of points) from list 1 (a0,a1,a2...aN-1) to the other elements in list 2 (b0,b1,b2...bN-1) so that we chose the shortest distances? eventually, we'd need to print the maximum distance among all minimum distances we have found for each of the elements.

Thanks

Comment: This question will get better answers on [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't even get what you mean.

Comment: This is an assignment problem; my first try would be with a mixed-integer programming solver.

Comment: @V0_1D I have edited with an example.

Comment: so basically for each point in list a, you want the point in list b which is closest to it?

Comment: More specifically, it's a balanced assignment problem, and the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) can solve it in polynomial time.